# How to save a Python list of arrays of varied dimensions to mat file

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I am going to save a `list` of arrays into a file that can be read in `Matlab`. The arrays in the list are of 3-dimensional but varied shapes, so I cannot put them into a single large array.

Originally I thought I could save the list in to a `pickle` file and then read the file in `Matlab`. Later I found `Matlab` does not support reading the `pickle` file. I also tried using `scipy.io.savemat` to save the list to a `mat` file. The inconsistencies of array dimensions causes saving problems.

Anyone has ideas of how to solve the problem? It should be noted that the list file is very large in memory (>4 G).

Comment: Not sure if MATLAB supports `json`, but `pickle` is Python specific while `json` is more universal...

Comment: @jez: This applies to numpy array ,not for list. I want to load the data into a cell array in Matlab

Comment: The nearest (in fact only) Matlab equivalent of a "list" (of variably-sized arrays) is a cell array.  If you want to save a list of variably-sized arrays and have Matlab read them, use a cell array.

Answer (score 1):

`savemat` is the right tool for saving numpy arrays in a MATLAB format.  I'd suggest making a desired structure in MATLAB, save it, and `loadmat`.  Duplicate that layout when going the other way.

Also `loadmat` the `savemat` file to get a better idea how it maps python objects onto MATLAB ones.

Arrays may become order F 2d arrays.  Cells may  become object dtype arrays, structs may become structured arrays.

Create a .mat` from a list:

```
In [180]: io.savemat('test.mat', {'x':[np.arange(12).reshape(3,4), np.arange(3), 4]})
```

reload it:

```
In [181]: data = io.loadmat('test.mat')                                                                              
In [182]: data                                                                                                       
Out[182]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Sat Mar 21 20:02:02 2020',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'x': array([[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]),
         array([[0, 1, 2]]), array([[4]])]], dtype=object)}
```

It has one named variable

```
In [183]: data['x']                                                                                                  
Out[183]: 
array([[array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]),
        array([[0, 1, 2]]), array([[4]])]], dtype=object)
```

The shape is 2d (like all MATLAB) and object dtype (to hold a mix of items):

```
In [185]: data['x'].shape                                                                                            
Out[185]: (1, 3)
```

Within that is a 2d array:

```
In [186]: data['x'][0,0].shape                                                                                       
Out[186]: (3, 4)
```

If I check the `flags` I see `data['x']` is order `F`, F contiguous (but the source, used in the `savemat` was default `C` contiguous).

Note also the change in shape of the 1d array and scalar - again following MATLAB conventions.

In Octave:

```
>> data = load('test.mat')
data =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    x =
    {
      [1,1] =

         0   1   2   3
         4   5   6   7
         8   9  10  11

      [1,2] =

        0  1  2

      [1,3] = 4
    }
```

we get a `cell` variable.

If I wanted a `numpy` matrix that didn't get changed in this transfer, I'd have to start with something like:

```
In [188]: np.arange(12).reshape(3,4,order='F')                                                                       
Out[188]: 
array([[ 0,  3,  6,  9],
       [ 1,  4,  7, 10],
       [ 2,  5,  8, 11]])
```

`numpy` is, by default `C` order, row-major, with first dimension being the outermost.  MATLAB is the opposite - F (fortran), column major, last dimension outermost.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a single file, you can iterate through the list and `savemat` each entry into a separate file. Then iterate through that directory and `load` each file into a cell array element.

You can also zip the directory you store these in, to get one file to pass around.